# VS Code can't detect JUnit from WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, gradle, junit, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use WSL 2 and connect to it through VS Code's remote window with `code .`, and VS Code shows it is connected to `WSL: Ubuntu`. JUnit is installed just fine and tests run perfectly from WSL, but VS Code won't stop complaining about missing the import. I am using a Gradle project.

I have tried some simplistic methods to attempt to get this to work, but nothing lets VS Code see the import.